# Copying data between spreadsheets from sheets with the same name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy the cell with the daily score from the sheets of all of my students in a spreadsheet where they are calculated and collected to another spreadsheet where they are used as currency to buy rewards. Both spreadsheets contain a sheet for every student that is named after that student, e.g. "John Smith"

The original google script that I created worked, but it was poor coding because I had to repeat the coding for every single name, and therefore add a new paragraph of code every time we get a new student. I would like to create a new google script that is more elegant and powerful and works without specifying the students' names so that it never needs to be amended. I can't quite get it and keep hitting a "Syntax error" with the last line.

```
function ImportDailyScore() {
  var dailyinput = "J27"; // Mon=J3, Tue=J9, Wed=J15, Thu=J21, Fri=J27
  var dollaroutput = "B2"; // Today=B2, Yesterday=B3, etc.

  var dollarspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var checkinspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('some id'); 
  var checkinsheets = checkinspreadsheet.getSheets(); // get all the sheets from check in doc
  var dollarsheets = dollarspreadsheet.getSheets(); // get all the sheets from dollar doc

  for (var i=0; i<checkinsheets.length; i++){ // loop across all the checkin sheets  
    var checkindata = checkinsheets[i].getRange(dailyinput).getValue();    
    var namedcheckin = checkinsheets[i].getSheetName()
    for (var j=0; j<dollarsheets.length; j++){
      var nameddollar = dollarsheets[j].getSheetName();
      if (namedcheckin = nameddollar, dollarsheets[j].getRange(dollaroutput).setValue(checkindata))
    }
  }
}
```

For reference, the original code (which works just as I would like it to) but needs to specify the name of every single student is:

```
function ImportDailyScore() {
  var dollarspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var checkinspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Y9Ys1jcm1xMaLSqmyl_pFnvIzbf-omSeIcaI2FgjFIs');
  var dailyinput = "J3"; // Mon=J3, Tue=J9, Wed=J15, Thu=J21, Fri=J27
  var dollaroutput = "B4"; // Today=B2, Yesterday=B3, etc.

  var JohnCHECKIN = checkinspreadsheet.getSheetByName('John Smith');
  var JohnCHECKINData = JohnCHECKIN.getRange(dailyinput).getValue();
  var JohnDOLLAR = dollarspreadsheet.getSheetByName('John Smith');
  JohnDOLLAR.getRange(dollaroutput).setValue(JohnCHECKINData);

  var JenniferCHECKIN = checkinspreadsheet.getSheetByName('Jennifer Scott');
  var JenniferCHECKINData = JenniferCHECKIN.getRange(dailyinput).getValue();
  var JenniferDOLLAR = dollarspreadsheet.getSheetByName('Jennifer Scott');
  JenniferDOLLAR.getRange(dollaroutput).setValue(JenniferCHECKINData);

  etc.
```

Comment: You are really close, your syntax issues can be solved by using `==` instead of `=`. More details can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp). Also, the syntax for if statement is explained [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).

Comment: Using Apps Script's automatic, syntax-based indentation (highlight all & press Tab) can really help you track your script logic. I've applied said indentation to your script -- perhaps now you can see the syntax issue with the `if` statement. There is of course still the **logic** error that @jack mentions, as you probably do not want to assign in that statement...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Because I'm really new to this, I'm never sure if I'm close or not. The links were exactly what I needed, and it's fixed now and working just as I'd hoped it would! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I don't have enough information to know how to handle the dollaroutput programmatically.

```
function ImportDailyScore() {
  var inputA=['','J3','J9','J15','J21','J27',''];
  var dailyinput = inputA[new Date().getDay()]; 
  if(dailyinput) {
    var dollaroutput = "B2"; // Today=B2, Yesterday=B3, etc. Not sure how to handle this programmatically I'd have to see the sheet
    var dollarspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var checkinspreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id'); 
    var checkinsheets = checkinspreadsheet.getSheets(); // get all the sheets from check in doc
    var dollarsheets = dollarspreadsheet.getSheets(); // get all the sheets from dollar doc
    for (var i=0; i<checkinsheets.length; i++){ // loop across all the checkin sheets  
      var checkindata = checkinsheets[i].getRange(dailyinput).getValue();    
      var namedcheckin = checkinsheets[i].getSheetName();
      for (var j=0; j<dollarsheets.length; j++){
        var nameddollar = dollarsheets[j].getSheetName();
        if (namedcheckin == nameddollar) {
          dollarsheets[j].getRange(dollaroutput).setValue(checkindata);
        }
      }
    }
  }else{
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(Utilities.formatString('Today is %s no school.', Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E")));
  }

}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for that @Cooper! I hadn't got to the point of getting the script to pull the date and execute automatically, but I think that is the next task! Currently I manually assign the "dollaroutput" and "dailyinput" and then manually trigger the script.

Comment: Because my colleague doesn't always get his students' scores in by the end of the day (or even the next day), I often just go back and trigger the script for the relevant day and input once I notice that he has got that done. But I think getting the script to automatically execute every evening both for the current day, and for the previous days in that week would be ideal. I'll get to it!!!

Comment: You could make the function like this `function ImportDailyScore(dailyinput) {
  var inputA=['','J3','J9','J15','J21','J27',''];
  var dailyinput = dailyinput || inputA[new Date().getDay()];  `